# Getting ComplianceException while deploying EJB in Weblogic

Tags: exception, ejb

Whenever I am trying to deploy ap application that uses EJB on Weblogic 12, I am getting the following exception:

> weblogic.ejb.container.compliance.ComplianceException

I am providing the stackTrace below:

```
weblogic.ejb.container.compliance.ComplianceException: In EJB Activity, the throws clause for method processRequest(java.lang.String,java.util.HashMap) in the bean class contains exceptions that are NOT in the throws clause of the remote interface.
at weblogic.ejb.container.compliance.EJBObjectClassChecker.checkInterfaceBusinessMethodsMatchBeanMethods(EJBObjectClassChecker.java:256)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at weblogic.ejb.container.compliance.EJBComplianceChecker.check(EJBComplianceChecker.java:98)
at weblogic.ejb.container.compliance.EJBComplianceChecker.check(EJBComplianceChecker.java:88)
at weblogic.ejb.container.compliance.EJBComplianceChecker.checkDeploymentInfo(EJBComplianceChecker.java:79)
at weblogic.ejb.container.ejbc.EJBCompiler.doCompile(EJBCompiler.java:172)
at weblogic.ejb.container.ejbc.EJBCompiler.compileEJB(EJBCompiler.java:336)
at weblogic.ejb.container.ejbc.EJBCompiler.compileEJB(EJBCompiler.java:304)
at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBDeployer.compileEjbs(EJBDeployer.java:425)
at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBDeployer.compileIfNecessary(EJBDeployer.java:356)
at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBDeployer.prepare(EJBDeployer.java:724)
at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBModule.prepare(EJBModule.java:405)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$PrepareStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:295)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$PrepareStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:285)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:109)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:192)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:187)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
at weblogic.work.ContextWrap.run(ContextWrap.java:46)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:681)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:655)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)




at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBDeployer.compileEjbs(EJBDeployer.java:427)
at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBDeployer.compileIfNecessary(EJBDeployer.java:356)
at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBDeployer.prepare(EJBDeployer.java:724)
at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBModule.prepare(EJBModule.java:405)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$PrepareStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:295)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Please help.